# Cisco Unified Call Manager SQL query

Tags: sql, cisco, ucos, cucm

I am trying to query call manager 8.5+ directly from the cli (eventually i will put this into axl)

currently my query looks like this

```
run sql select dp.name as Site, tm.name as Model, count(tm.name) as Total from Device as d inner join DevicePool as dp on(d.fkDevicePool = dp.pkid) inner join typemodel as tm on(tm.enum = d.tkmodel) where (tm.name <> 'Analog Phone' and tm.name <> 'Conference Bridge'  and tm.name <> 'CTI Route Point' and tm.name <> 'CTI Port' and tm.name <> 'MGCP Station' and tm.name <> 'Route List' and tm.name <> 'H.323 Gateway' and tm.name <> 'Music On Hold' and tm.name <> 'Media Termination Point' and tm.name <> 'Tone Announcement Player' and tm.name <> 'Cisco IOS Conference Bridge (HDV2)' and tm.name <> 'Cisco IOS Software Media Termination Point (HDV2)' and tm.name <> 'Cisco IOS Media Termination Point (HDV2)' and tm.name <> 'SIP Trunk') group by dp.name, tm.name order by dp.name
```

this results in this

```
site           model                             total
============== ================================= =====
SITE1-NUANCE-DP Third-party SIP Device (Advanced) 1
SITE1-PHONES-DP Cisco 8945                        351
SITE1-PHONES-DP Cisco 6941                        25
SITE1-PHONES-DP Cisco 7925                        310
SITE1-PHONES-DP Cisco 7937                        3
SITE1-PHONES-DP Cisco 8961                        293
SITE1-PHONES-DP Cisco IP Communicator             1
SITE2-PHSRST-DP Cisco 7937                        1
SITE2-PHSRST-DP Cisco 6941                        1
SITE2-PHSRST-DP Cisco 8961                        143
SITE2-PHSRST-DP Cisco 8945                        21
```

What i really want to see though is something like this

```
site           total
============== =====
SITE1-PHONES-DP 300
SITE2-PHONES-DP 350
```

I'll be upfront here, i learned the little bit of sql i know yesterday from web searches. I dont know if you can do string manipulation or anything, because really i would like to drop the -phones-dp portion under site but it's not critical. I just need to have the query allow people bad at math to get a number. in the current state, they have to add everything up which could be DISASTROUS!  Any help is greatly appreciated! thanks!

Comment: Check out the typeclass table.  The device table has a reference to it and it can help filter your results without 'tm.name <>'

You could also process the results (ie apply filters, calculations) in whatever you're using to place the AXL call.  This can offload some cycles from the CUCM which could be busy processing calls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on what you have stated, I would try something like this:

```
select dp.name as Site
,count(tm.name) as Total 
from Device as d 
inner join DevicePool as dp on(d.fkDevicePool = dp.pkid) 
inner join typemodel as tm on(tm.enum = d.tkmodel) 
where (
        tm.name <> 'Analog Phone' 
        and tm.name <> 'Conference Bridge'  
        and tm.name <> 'CTI Route Point' 
        and tm.name <> 'CTI Port' 
        and tm.name <> 'MGCP Station' 
        and tm.name <> 'Route List' 
        and tm.name <> 'H.323 Gateway' 
        and tm.name <> 'Music On Hold' 
        and tm.name <> 'Media Termination Point' 
        and tm.name <> 'Tone Announcement Player' 
        and tm.name <> 'Cisco IOS Conference Bridge (HDV2)' 
        and tm.name <> 'Cisco IOS Software Media Termination Point (HDV2)' 
        and tm.name <> 'Cisco IOS Media Termination Point (HDV2)' 
        and tm.name <> 'SIP Trunk'
    ) 
group by dp.name
order by dp.name
```

Comment: Also, research the replace function as it would help you to remove "-PHONES-DP" from the field "dp.name"

Comment: Good call on the replace! i was using java to run the query and put into xml, then using powershell to remove the -PHONES-DP from the xml and export to csv! doing it all in SQL is much nicer :D